# Shiftr expected a spec of Map type, got ArrayList

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm working around with [nifi-JoltTransformJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/) processor [1.9.2] version I have an input json as shown below with the spec json as an attribute.

Input JSON:

```
{
"Your order":
{
"order_id":2116,
"products":[
{
"productId":"abc",
"productName":"Headphones",
"Cost":500
},
{
"productId":"cad",
"productName":"Laptop",
"Cost":89000
}
],
"total":90000
},
"location":{
"address":"No: 1338 MIG-1 Asian"
}
}
```

Spec :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "location": "counterTop"
    }
    }
]
```

I am receiving an expected output on the demo-jolt site link: http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

But on Nifi-1.9.2 version i receive the below error:

Error on nifi-logs:

```
com.bazaarvoice.jolt.exception.SpecException: Shiftr expected a spec of Map type, got ArrayList
    at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr.<init>(Shiftr.java:480)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.jolt.TransformFactory.getTransform(TransformFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.createTransform(JoltTransformJSON.java:348)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.lambda$setup$0(JoltTransformJSON.java:324)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON$$Lambda$752/36325009.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:3366)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache$$Lambda$240/1329040766.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2039)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$$Lambda$756/2085882783.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2037)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2020)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:112)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:67)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.getTransform(JoltTransformJSON.java:316)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.onTrigger(JoltTransformJSON.java:277)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1171)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any suggestions to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the specs to this and it will work.
You just need to iterate over each item inside your array and again fill an array inside the json. worked for me

[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"locations": {
"*": {
"@": "countertop[]"
}
},
"*": {
"@": "&"
}
}
}
]